# How to say "So, yeah..." in German?

Tags: translation, english-to-german

How do you say "So, yeah" in German?

E.g.:

> So, yeah I need to get going.

Here's my attempt:

> Also, muss ich verlassen.

Comment: I must say, I'm curious as to why you've just _assumed_ an American audience who don't need any exposition regarding this American idiom. Stack Exchange is an international community and I'd have thought it's self-evident that German.SE most _certainly_ has an international flavour. That means you shall _identify_/_explain_ your localised idioms when asking about them, instead of bringing this offensive Americentricism to the table. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, you can't say *verlassen* without an object. "I have to leave" is better translated as "Ich muss gehen" or more idiomatically "Ich muss los."

Comment: Additionally, *also* doesn't change the verb position when it's used as a filler. *Also, ich muss los*. You'd move the verb when it means "so" as in "because," like *Ich habe jetzt Termin, also muss ich los.*

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Do you mean this as a filler word to end a conversation and turn away?

I think this differs from speaker to speaker.

A young person could say:

> Ok, ich muss dann mal los.

Other informal ways are:

> Also dann, ich gehe dann mal.
>
> Na gut, ich muss (los).

Starting with *„Also, …“* is possible, but I would expect it to be stretched in this context and with a short break before going on with this set phrase (e.g. *„Alsooo … ich mache mich dann mal los.“*)

In a more formal context I could imagine

> Gut, ich muss mich (dann) auf den Weg machen.

Please note that especially the informal examples could be considered as rude when using them to end a conversation. If unsure, explain briefly why you have to leave.